# cannot start sinatra process - eventmachine "no acceptor"

Tags: ruby, apache, sinatra, eventmachine

I have a Sinatra app that I run as a daemon, using Apache port-forwarding to mediate between port 80 and port 7655. This has been working fine in the past. Today, not so well. I cannot figure out why.

Problem: `sudo ruby my_process.rb` returns:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
```

Tried: updating all system packages, updating all gems. No help (except for the more clear error message from eventmachine).

When I run `sudo lsof -i :7655` I get nothing back. When I run `sudo ps aux` I don't see *any* Ruby processes at all. Which I find highly irregular, given the nature of the error message!

So is there something I'm missing in finding out why the port is unavailable?

---

Also:

Tried changing ports, nothing. I wonder if it is related to "localhost"? When I ping localhost I get all dropped packets. That doesn't seem normal.

Comment: What exactly are you using to run `my_process.rb`?

Comment: Sorry, should have read `sudo ruby my_process.rb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out these two lines in the main Sinatra script provided the most information:

```
set bind: "localhost"
set port: 7655
```

The problem was with localhost. The loopback interface was not properly configured. `ifconfig` showed the `lo` interface, but it hadn't been assigned the IP `127.0.0.1`. To resolve, ran the following commands in the shell (on an Ubuntu Linux system):

```
ifdown lo
ifup lo
```

Comment: can you provide a bit more detail about this answer. Where did you put "ifdown lo" and "ifup lo" if that's the solution. I can't figure out what to do...

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil: "ifdown" AND "ifup" are Linux/MacOS commands to start and stop the "loopback" ("software") network adapter.  They should *not* be necessary for your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049765/port-in-use-when-not-using-a-port).  The key thing is to change the "bind" address in your Sinatra script, and see if it helps the "port in use" error you're currently getting for port#4567.

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks, but i've never had to set a bind address before, and setting it now isn't working. I updated the OP with a little more information which may explain the source of the problem even if I cant' see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you close term sometime you forget to stop [CTRL+C] the actual server, just run the following command to kill all ruby process like sinatra, and run-it again

```
killall ruby
```

You can see your actual ruby process by running

```
ps -ef | grep ruby
```